# How to represent recursive Object structure of JSON Documents in C++?

Tags: c++, json, recursion

I want to represent a json-like file, like the following ...

```
{
    root_att_0: 23,
    root_att_1:
    {
        root_att_1_att_0: "Peter",
        root_att_1_att_1: 3.14f
    },
    root_att_2: ["Hello", "World"],
    root_att_3:
    {
        root_att_3_att_0: 64,
        root_att_3_att_1:
        {
            root_att_3_att_1_att_0: 123
        }
    },
    root_att_4: true
}
```

in C++ using a Tree structure like in the following diagram ...

[json structure diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJnoe.png)

I have tried to implement that representation with the following code ...

```
using JSONType = std::variant
<
    bool,
    int,
    float,
    double,
    std::string,

    std::vector<bool>,
    std::vector<int>,
    std::vector<float>,
    std::vector<double>,
    std::vector<std::string>
>;

struct JSONObject
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::variant<JSONType, JSONObject>> attributes;
};

int main()
{
    JSONObject o
    {
        {"string", std::variant<JSONType, JSONObject>(JSONType(true))}
    };
}
```

but on initializing the JSONObject o with an unordered_map entry I always get the following error. I don't understand why the values that I have given in the initialization
are wrong...

```
no instance of constructor "std::unordered_map<_Kty, _Ty, _Hasher, 
_Keyeq, _Alloc>::unordered_map [with _Kty=std::string, 
_Ty=std::variant<JSONType, JSONObject>, 
_Hasher=std::hash<std::string>, _Keyeq=std::equal_to<std::string>,
_Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, 
std::variant<JSONType, JSONObject>>>]" matches the argument list
argument types are: (const char [7], std::variant<JSONType, JSONObject>)
```

Comment: *"I don't understand why the values that I have given in the initialization are wrong.."* -- instead of trying to understand why it is wrong, could you explain why you think it should be correct? (See also [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).)

Comment: You probably just need an extra pair of braces in your initialiser, 1 for the object, 1 for the map and 1 for the element

Comment: @JaMiT I was operating under the assumption that  `{"string", std::variant<JSONType, JSONObject>(JSONType(true))}` is a map-entry where the std::string "string" is the key  and either a JSONType ( bool, int, ... ) or a JSONObject, another unordered_map with the same properties, is the value.

Comment: @Alan Birtles You're absolutely correct. Now that you said it, it's obvious. As always. Can i set you'r comment as the correct answer somehow ?

Comment: I am not shure I named this question properly. Any tips on how to improve it ? Naming it something like "Error on initializing an unordered_map" would have more to do with the actual problem, but seems like a worse title to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject o
    {
        {"string", std::variant<JSONType, JSONObject>(JSONType(true))}
    };
```

Is missing a set of braces. You need one set for `JSONObject`, one for the `attributes` member and a final set for the map entry:

```
JSONObject o
    {
      {
        {"string", std::variant<JSONType, JSONObject>(JSONType(true))}
      }
    };
```